# How do I use a while loop to count results?

Tags: python

Example:

```
choice(['Aa', 'Bb', 'Cc')
```

Should print:

```
Enter choice: Aa
Enter choice: Cc
Enter choice: Aa
Enter choice: Aa
Enter choice: Bb
Enter choice: Cc
Enter choice: Aa
Enter choice:

There are 4 choices for Aa.

There are 2 choices for Cc.

There are 1 choices for Bb.

There is 1 choice for Unknown.
```

Notice that it keeps asking what your choice is until there is a blank.

so far:

def choice(n):

```
while True:

    vote = input('Enter choice: ')
```

Comment: this kind of looks like homework where the teacher gave you how the user is suppose to interact with it and asks you to write it.

Comment: `from collections import Counter`

Comment: This isn't a question it's a requirement.

Comment: i am confused on how to use while loops all together

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like homework, so here's some pseudocode:

```
function choice gets an options list

    counter is a dictionary
    for each option in the options list
        counter[option] is 0
    counter[unknown] is 0

    loop
        ask for input
        if input is blank
            exit the loop
        otherwise if input is in the option array
            increment counter[input]
        otherwise
            increment counter[unknown]

    for each option in the options list
        "Option {option} had {counter[option]} votes"
    "Option unknown had {counter[unknown]} votes"
```